# Speech_recognition py2exe subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, speech-recognition, py2exe

I am trying to create a standalone executable from a python script using `py2exe`. The script uses Google's `speech_recognition` module. I tried a lot of things I found on a google search but nothing seems to fix the problem (tried importing `subprocess` in the `setup.py` file, including every single module my script could possibly use, etc).

Any ideas? (P.S: I don't really want to change from `py2exe` to `pyinstaller` because it has an unsolved bug in another module I need in my script). This is what I am getting after a certain point in the execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "core_v_0.1.py", line 210, in <module>
  search_for_series()
  File "core_v_0.1.py", line 111, in search_for_series
    answer=user_speech_recognition()
  File "core_v_0.1.py", line 147, in user_speech_recognition
    user_said_=r.recognize_google(audio) 
  File "speech_recognition\__init__.pyc", line 608, in recognize_g 
  File "speech_recognition\__init__.pyc", line 351, in get_flac_da
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 710, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 958, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's trying to run `flac.exe` to compress the audio
and that exe is not bundled by `py2exe`. To force an arbitrary file to be included
use [`data_file` param](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) to `setup` in setup.py like this:

```
setup(
    ....
    data_files = [('path/to/googlespeachhelpers', ['/path/to/googlespeachflac.exe']]
    ....
)
```

I haven't played with google speach, so the paths must be checked, eg where the module expects to find flac.exe.